# R overload assignment operator (`<-`)

Tags: r, operator-overloading, operators

Hi I am experimenting with R's S3 classes. So I ran into a problem after following https://www.r-bloggers.com/object-oriented-programming-in-r/. In the class `nc <- list2env(nc)` is used to save the object in its own environment, I will be creating objects that will contain large datasets so I like the pointer style a lot. The problem comes in when you want to create a copy of the object (`newObject<-oldObject`), this only creates a copy of the pointer to the object and not a copy of the object. This is a problem because if I change something of either the old or new object both would register the same change.

I was thinking if I could overload the `<-` operator with my own function that copies the object into a new environment it would be great. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know I can clone the environment with:

```
newObject<- as.environment(as.list(oldObject, all.names=TRUE))
```

but when I try to overload the assignment operator it does not work, i.e.

`'<-.MyClass'<-function(NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD COME HERE){
 newObject<- as.environment(as.list(oldObject, all.names=TRUE))
 return(newObject)
}`

I have gotten it to work with other operators eg +, *

Comment: `<-` isn't a S3 generic so you won't just be able to define a method for your class.  Is there a reason you can't just define a new function to do what you want and need to override `<-`?

Comment: Why using an environment as inner storage structure, if you want the object to be cloned everytime is assigned (i.e. `b <- a` clones a) ? Just use a string as storage structure...in other words, remove the line `nc <- list2env(nc)`

Comment: Why not create a simple `copyMyClass` function that copies an environment to a new one and, simply, use `newObject <- copyMyClass(oldObject)`? btw, `as.environment(as.list(oldObject, all.names=TRUE))` can be replaced with a more efficient version of `new = new.env(); for(elt in names(old)) new[[elt]] = old[[new]]`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks I'll you it as such in the future!
The reason I want to not write a function like copyMyClass is because people not familiar with R nvm my class will be using it and will use what they know when they create copies.

Comment: @GeyerBisschoff : Depending on your actual structures, you could, probably, control the copying behaviour through arguments of your functions or build a background control flow specific to your class that could assess whether something exists or is being overwritten. Other than that, you could create a suitable API and workflow for your class -- e.g. `new = makeInstantOfMyClass(); new[] = old` where, here, you can overload `[<-` and copy "old" to "new".